# How to output integer arrays to file in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3000000 ints' long array which I want to output to a file. How can I do that?
Also, is this

```
for i in range(1000):
    for k in range(1000):
        (r, g, b) = rgb_im.getpixel((i, k))
        rr.append(r)
        gg.append(g)
        bb.append(b)
d.extend(rr)
d.extend(gg)
d.extend(bb)
```

a good practice to join array together?

All of the arrays are declared like this `d = array('B')`

EDIT:
Managed to output all int`s delimited by ' ' with this

```
from PIL import Image
import array

side = 500

for j in range(1000):
    im = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Ivars\Desktop\RS\Shape\%02d.jpg' % (j))
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    d = array.array('B')
    rr = array.array('B')
    gg = array.array('B')
    bb = array.array('B')
    f = open(r'C:\Users\Ivars\Desktop\RS\ShapeData\%02d.txt' % (j), 'w')
    for i in range(side):
        for k in range(side):
            (r, g, b) = rgb_im.getpixel((i, k))
            rr.append(r)
            gg.append(g)
            bb.append(b)
    d.extend(rr)
    d.extend(gg)
    d.extend(bb)
    o = ' '.join(str(t) for t in d)
    print('#', j, ' - ', len(o))
    f.write(o)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Those aren't lists. Are you using the `array` module?

Comment: In that case I am confused how similar things are often addressed by being a list or array. Yes, I am.
Replaced "lists" with "arrays" in the question.

Comment: The people calling lists arrays are generally new to Python; they haven't gotten used to the terminology yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using python >= 2.6 then you can use print functions from the *future*!

```
from __future__ import print_function

#your code

# This will print out a string representation of list to the file.
# If you need it formatted differently, then you'll have to construct the string yourself
print(d, file=open('/path/to/file.txt','w')

#you can join the list items with an empty string to get only the numbers
print("".join(d),file=('/path/to/file.txt','w'))
```

This has the side effect of turning print from a statement into a function, so you'll have to wrap whatever you want printed in ()

Comment: How can I reformat the data? It currently prints like this `array('B', [0, 0, 0, (...), 0, 0, 0]) w`. How can I output only numbers like '0000'?

Comment: I've added a snippet, if that doesn't do exactly what you need, then Google 'join list python' for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You want `tofile()`, which requires you to open a file object.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects.  Also, have you considered using NumPy?

```
import array
a = array.array('B')
b = array.array('B')
a.append(3)
a.append(4)
print a
print b
with open('c:/test.dat', 'w') as f:
    a.tofile(f)
with open('c:/test.dat', 'r') as f:
    b.fromfile(f, 2)
print b
```

EDIT:  Based on your edit, you can use numpy with PIL and generate the array in a line or two, without looping.  See, e.g., [Conversion between Pillow Image object and numpy array changes dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016144/conversion-between-pillow-image-object-and-numpy-array-changes-dimension) for example code.

Comment: Do you mean using numpy arrays? I have numpy installed.
What advantage do numpy arrays have?

Comment: tofile returns
`d.tofile(f) TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

Comment: Does make code work correctly for you? It's self-contained, and worked when I tried it.